# Drools project build failure with kjar packaging starting from version 7.7

Tags: java, maven, drools

I'm new to maven and drools. I'm working on java/DROOLS project. When I want to build a project using `kjar` packaging type, with drools versions higher than 7.7.0,by typing the command `mvn clean package` it throws an error message. However, for lower versions of drools, for example  7.6.0, build is successful. I would use 7.6.0 version, but there are bugs that are solved only in recent versions.

I tried to change versions of drools, so I stopped at 7.6.0. It is highest successful version. Also, I changed type of packaging to jar and maven successfully built the project for all versions, but I need `kjar` packaging type for kie-server.

Here is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>testProject</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>kjar</packaging>
  <name>Drools :: Sample Maven Project</name>
  <description>A sample Drools Maven project</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <runtime.version>7.22.0.Final</runtime.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>${runtime.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>${runtime.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <version>${runtime.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbpm-test</artifactId>
            <version>${runtime.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
                <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${runtime.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <resources>
                        <resources>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        </resources>
                        <testResources>
                            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                        </testResources>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>myMavenRepoWrite</id>
            <url>${myMavenRepoWriteUrl}</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>myMavenRepoWrite</id>
            <url>${myMavenRepoWriteUrl}</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
                    <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
                    <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
                    <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
                    <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.431 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-03T11:18:33+06:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.22.0.Final:build (default-build) on project testProject: Execution default-build of goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.22.0.Final:build failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.22.0.Final:build (default-build) on project testProject: Execution default-build of goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.22.0.Final:build failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-build of goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.22.0.Final:build failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.drools.decisiontable.parser.DefaultRuleSheetListener.flushRule (DefaultRuleSheetListener.java:306)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.parser.DefaultRuleSheetListener.finishSheet (DefaultRuleSheetListener.java:286)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.parser.xls.ExcelParser.finishSheet (ExcelParser.java:285)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.parser.xls.ExcelParser.processSheet (ExcelParser.java:220)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.parser.xls.ExcelParser.parseWorkbook (ExcelParser.java:111)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.parser.xls.ExcelParser.parseFile (ExcelParser.java:85)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.parseResource (SpreadsheetCompiler.java:136)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.compile (SpreadsheetCompiler.java:120)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.compile (SpreadsheetCompiler.java:93)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.DecisionTableProviderImpl.compileResource (DecisionTableProviderImpl.java:70)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.DecisionTableProviderImpl.loadFromResource (DecisionTableProviderImpl.java:42)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.DecisionTableFactory.loadFromResource (DecisionTableFactory.java:36)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.decisionTableToPackageDescr (KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:415)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl$ResourceToPkgDescrMapper.lambda$static$4 (CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:327)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildResource (CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:199)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildPackageDescr (CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:186)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.build (CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:108)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.build (CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:100)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.buildKnowledgePackages (AbstractKieProject.java:261)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.verify (AbstractKieProject.java:75)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieProject (KieBuilderImpl.java:270)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll (KieBuilderImpl.java:238)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll (KieBuilderImpl.java:187)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.getKieModule (KieBuilderImpl.java:493)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.getKieModule (KieBuilderImpl.java:483)
    at org.kie.maven.plugin.BuildMojo.buildDrl (BuildMojo.java:169)
    at org.kie.maven.plugin.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

If you want to reproduce the problem, here is link:
https://github.com/Kusbek/droolsTestProject

Comment: It sounds like a bug. Can you please open a ticket on https://issues.jboss.org ? Thank you very much

Comment: @LucaMolteni, thank you for response. Created issue. [link](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-4123)